# Auto Start/Stop of AWS instance in case of a none responsive system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, interrupt

Sometimes I'm experiencing that an AWS instance is using 100% of the CPU resources - because of a conflict between the hardware and software virtualization. More exact it is the process called "System interrupts" which consumes all CPU resources. This is simply solved by stopping the instance, wait a while and then start the instance again (hereby it will startup on other hardware - just a restart would not work).

My question is now: What is the easiest way to stop the AWS instance and after 1 min start the instance up again automatically when the system is none-responsive? Can this somehow be done within AWS ecosystem itself?

The not so easy way would be to get another system to ping the server and if it doesn't respond - then I could execute a custom script with the needed actions. But I'm hoping an easier solution exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CloudWatch Alarm for when the instance reaches a certain percentage in CPU.

Add a trigger for during AlertState to trigger a Lambda. The Lambda would call the AWS CLI to run the StopInstance method, then sleep for 1 minute, then run the StartInstance method.

Example function: https://www.howtoforge.com/aws-lambda-function-to-start-and-stop-ec2-instance/

Comment: Hey my friend! Thank you so much! It sound exactly like what I have been searching for! :-) I will return to you when I have the time to go through all steps and test it out! Cheers!

Comment: FYI: I have tried to accept this answer my friend - but something seems not to be working 100% with StackOverflow atm. it doesn't mark the answer as accepted / with the green checkmark... I will try again in a couple of days : Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Amazon CloudWatch Alarm** in the Amazon EC2 management console:

- Select the EC2 instance
- Go to the **Monitoring** tab
- Click **Create Alarm**
- Configure `Take the action: Reboot this instance`

This will attempt a graceful restart of the operating system, but will force the restart if necessary.

You can configure the alarm to trigger after a given period of 100% CPU. Just be careful that it doesn't trigger when the instance is simply doing "real" work. You might need to play around with the alarm settings to get it just right.

Comment: As mentioned in my post a "restart" is not enough - I need a true stop -> pause -> start for the issue to disappear :)  But according to @mokugo-devops post below  - CloudWatch can fix this as well :)